# Solution (non-zero) for $\frac{dy}{dx} = |y|^{\alpha}, y(0) = 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, absolute-value

I am having difficulty finding an approach for the following problem:

**Problem:** "Take an arbitrary $\alpha \in (0,1)$.  Construct a non-zero solution for

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = |y|^{\alpha}, y(0) = 0$$

and then show that there are infinitely many solutions.

*Hint*: First find a solution in the following form:

\begin{equation*}
    y(x) = 
    \begin{cases}
    0, \quad &\text{if } x \leq 0\\
Cx^\beta &\text{otherwise}
    \end{cases}
\end{equation*}

with C and $\beta > 0$ to be determined."

**My attempt**: I solved the ODE for $y > 0$ and then $y < 0$, but didn't know what to do from there.

\begin{align}
    &\text{When } y > 0 \Rightarrow y(x) = ((1 - \alpha)x)^{-(1-\alpha)}\\
    &\text{When } y < 0 \Rightarrow y(x) = -((1 - \alpha)x)^{-(1-\alpha)}
\end{align}

But I don't know where to go from here, or if this is the right first step at all. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: So sorry! I forgot a crucial detail which is that alpha must be from 0 to 1 non-inclusive.

Answer (score 1):

If you plug $y=C x^{\beta}$ in the ODE we obtain conditions on $C$ and $\beta$.
We get
$$
C\beta x^{\beta-1} = C^\alpha x^{\alpha \beta}.
$$
Hence we need $\beta-1=\alpha \beta$ and $C=C^\alpha$, i.e. $C\equiv 1$ (otherwise we get the trivial solution) and $\beta=\frac{1}{1-\alpha}\in (1,\infty)$.